# How other thread can show the incremented value unless the 1st thread reaches the return statement?

Tags: java, multithreading

My code is given below.

In the for loop I am getting unexpected output i.e.
before completing the execution of for loop by 1st thread the 2nd thread comes in for loop and shows incremented value.

```
public class ThreadSafe {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("main()");

        B b=new B("1st Thread");
        B b1=new B("2nd Thread");
        B b2=new B("3rd Thread");
        b.start();
        b1.start();
        b2.start();
    }
}

class MyCounter {
    private static int count;

    public static int getCount(){
        for(int m=0;m<2;m++){
            System.out.println(count+" "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
        }

        return count++;
    }         
}

class B extends Thread{
    public B(String tname) {
        super(tname);
    }

public void run() {
    MyCounter.getCount();
    }
}
```

The question is when 1st thread executes for loop then other threads executing return statement is this the reason of showing increment value or something else?

How other thread can show the incremented value unless the 1st thread reaches the return statement?

Answer (score 1):

first 2 points to make:

1. there is not guarantee that the thread's execution will be interleaved, short pieces of code will likely complete uninterrupted. Add sleeps if you want to lessen this effect.
2. `count++` is not thread safe, it expands to `int tmp=count; count=tmp+1;` and the thread may be interrupted between the `tmp=count` and `count=tmp+1`. Instead use an `AtomicInt` and `incrementAndGet`.

The increment of the static count may not be visible to the other thread, it takes a while before changes to a variable become visible to other threads. Using a `volatile` field will lessen that but you will still see points 1 and 2 in effect.

Also print statements are buffered before being written out so the order of the print statements don't necessarily mean that they were called in that order.

Comment: i agree sir, but question is that which thread is executing count++.Because count++ is outside the loop as a return stmt. so if first thread is executing first cycle of for loop before reaching to count++ then in second cycle of loop for first thread showing incremented value.How??

Comment: @avi the first thread reached the end of it's timeslice between cycles and another thread incremented count

Comment: didn't understand...

Comment: @avi why don't you add the output you get to the question instead of trying to explain it

Comment: o/p are varying.
when i run this prog first time then i get like this-
main()
0 2nd Thread
0 2nd Thread
0 1st Thread
1 1st Thread
0 3rd Thread
2 3rd Thread

Comment: It means the second thread went through the entire loop first and before it exited the first and third thread went through a cycle, then the first thread completed the last cycle and returned and then the third thread finished. It's not a surprising result honestly

Comment: this is another o/p. sir Is it like print the statements and thread execution is different?
main()
0 1st Thread
1 3rd Thread
1 3rd Thread
2 1st Thread
0 2nd Thread
0 2nd Thread

Comment: ok.Thanks sir something i have understood?

Comment: What do you see, and what do you expect? And why do you expect what you expect?

Comment: Sir, Plz see this o/p and tell me why value is not incrementing from 1 to 2 despite of completing the cycle either of 3rd Thread
or 2nd Thread.??
main()
0 1st Thread
0 1st Thread
1 2nd Thread
1 3rd Thread
1 3rd Thread
1 2nd Thread

Comment: Adding sleeps just dodges a race condition and creates another one.  If there is a certain order that things must execute, either do it sequentially or Pou barriers in the threads to make sure everything lines up.

Answer (score 0):

[Example output](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/239144/how-other-thread-can-show-the-incremented-value-unless-the-1st-thread-reaches-th#comment480641_239147):

```
0 1st Thread
1 3rd Thread
1 3rd Thread
2 1st Thread
0 2nd Thread
0 2nd Thread
```

What you're seeing here is that your threads have locally cached your `count` variable, as it is not declared as [being volatile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volatile_variable#In_Java):

> When applied to a field, the Java volatile guarantees that:
>
> (In all versions of Java) There is a global ordering on the reads and writes to a volatile variable. This implies that every thread accessing a volatile field will read its current value before continuing, **instead of (potentially) using a cached value**.

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

Being volatile won't save your counter from misbehaving under `++` though, [as it is not an atomic operation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomic.html):

> [That] an increment expression, such as counter++, does not describe an atomic action. Even very simple expressions can define complex actions that can decompose into other actions[...]  Atomic actions cannot be interleaved, so they can be used without fear of thread interference.

The [Java tutorial on concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html) is a great place to learn about these things.